# AutoCompleteTexView not changing the view of dropdown list

Tags: android, view, autocompletetextview

My AutoCompleteTexView doesn't update the view on a particular char sequence entered, It updates the view on other times but on Entering "ca" in AutoCompleteTexView it doesn;t update the view, the List and data have been updated and it is being set too. But the View isn't getting updated, for all other sequence it the view is updated with appropriate results.

```
final AutoCompleteArrayListAdapter mAdapter = new AutoCompleteArrayListAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, oList);
mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);                 
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
```

Edit : Issue Resolved.

Resolved the issue by setting the Threshold which was "1" to "2".

Comment: That means that Your oList does not have any item with "CA".

Comment: @Zohra : Say we're searching Countries, If i Enter "CA" i get results for countries with CA {ex. CANADA}, but the view isn't updated. If i Enter "CAN" I'll get Canada in drop down, only issue with specific char sequence "CA"

Comment: Please post R.layout.spinner_item.

Comment: It's custom Spinner,
Resolved the issue by setting the threshold to 2.

Comment: why have u implemented onTextChanged. Even is you don't  AutoCompleteTextView will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a threshold value for the `AutoCompleteTexView`:

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
```

or define it in a layout file:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:completionThreshold="1"/>
```